# Eclipse Leiningen plugin installing issues

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Sorry for this question, I'm new to Clojure. I followed [this blog](http://cemerick.com/2012/05/02/starting-clojure/)
how to install Leiningen plugin for Eclipse and found out that link (http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite-lein-betas) for that plugin is broken.

[image]

Is there another way to install this plugin, or even better, a working link? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beta updatesite is http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite-betas/. The new CCW versions include leiningen integration, so they are no longer separate plugins.

Comment: Tried with both answers...still nothing. It only shows me an option to install Counterclockwise plugin.

Comment: As I said, the Counterclockwise plugin has incorporated the leiningen plugin for some time.

Answer (score 2):

that post is a bit old, the current update site (to put in that box in Eclipse) is:

```
http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/
```

Comment: I found it, I didn't know it comes with Counterclockwise now. Sorry for disturbing you, and thanks!